# HTTPS to HTTP Differnece between Classic and Application EC2 Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, bokeh

I have been used a classic load balancer on AWS Elastic Beanstalk which seems to map https requests inbound onto http into the instance. This means I can use an Amazon certificate on the load balancer and the instance does not need to deal with the HTTPS traffic. All great but when I try to use an application load balancer (which gives lots more functionality) I cannot redirect HTTPS onto HTTP.

Notwithstanding the security issues this seems to be a major functional difference - how do I use an AWS certificate (can I download the cert?) in this circumstance.

My certificate is at wildcard level for a domain - I have a primary Flask web  site and tornado server (Bokeh) on a separate instance - I am trying to get this working using Amazon certificate HTTPS and have got close but as yet no cigar.

My apologies if this a a no-brainer but have been bootstrapping this for a few days now.

Just for clarity - my site is including javascript serviced by a bokeh server and that needs to use an https reference otherwise I get that whole mixed content drama.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP** : It is hyper text transfer protocol.

**HTTPS** : It is hyper text transfer protocol secure.

**Classical Load Balancer** : Classic Load Balancer provides basic load balancing across multiple Amazon EC2 instances and operates at both the request level and connection level.

**Application Load Balancer** : Application Load Balancer is best suited for load balancing of HTTP and HTTPS traffic and provides advanced request routing targeted at the delivery of modern application architectures.

**How To do HTTPS to HTTP in EBS or EC2** :

For AWS certificate you can use AWS Certificate Manager which will be responsible to give you cert for your domain and now you need a Load Balancer which will redirect https public to http but according to your problem not doing that i think Load Balance need a API which it will check that the server is running or not . It directly didn't do anything you have to write this simple api which return 200 status now it know that server is running now it will transfer to http .